# Beginner on Ruby require syntax

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

A helpful article on here recommended to call Ruby gems explicitly even though they are built-in.

So instead of

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'falcon'#file to test
```

I wrote

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'falcon'# file to test
```

The second syntax solved the problems I had.

I am now wondering if the second header is correct, i.e. whether there are any unnecessary repetitions in it.

Comment: Unless you're running Ruby 1.8 or older, you don't need to `require 'rubygems'`. Your source article may be outdated.

Comment: What problem did you have in the first one that the second solved?

Comment: Odds are *very* good the article is outdated. If it isn't old it should be ignored because the author isn't paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

You should state your Ruby version too, as this will make it easier to find out the specific pattern of behaviour exhibited.

`require 'rubygems'` is no longer needed on more recent (~e. g. ~3 years old) Ruby versions.

To call Rubygems again explicitly makes no sense to me. Even if it were, I would consider this behavior a bug as the decision to integrate rubygems it was already made.

Rubygems comes bundled with default Ruby these days, the days of explicit `require 'rubygems'` ought to be over in my opinion.

Comment: "on more recent (~e. g. ~3 years old) Ruby versions". To be specific, Ruby 1.9+ automatically does a `require "rubygems"` so only Ruby < 1.9 needs it.